# Как объединить 2 фильтра css

Tags: html, css

```
filter: drop-shadow(8px 2px 6px #92a8ff);
filter: drop-shadow(8px 2px 6px #92a8ff);
```

Как объединить эти 2 фильтра в 1? (Или как сделать 1 более насыщенным? - С 1 фильтром результат не устраивает.)

Comment: `filter: drop-shadow(8px 2px 6px #92a8ff) drop-shadow(8px 2px 6px #92a8ff);` так?

Comment: А вообще покажите рабочий пример, что бы мы могли видеть, что вас не устраивает :)

Comment: Это было так просто? xD Спасибо, то что надо :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще все стили объединяются через пробел или, в редких случаях, через запятую. В вашем случае вот так напишите:

```
filter: drop-shadow(8px 2px 6px #92a8ff) drop-shadow(8px 2px 6px #92a8ff);
```